# Why is Mongrel failing to pick up the correct HTTP verb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, mongrel

I have an *extremely* simple `routes.rb` in my Rails app:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :tags
end
```

Starting up my app with `script/server` and pointing my browser to `localhost:3000/tags/` yields:

#### ActionController::MethodNotAllowed

```
Only get and post requests are allowed.
```

...

Starting up my app with `script/server webrick`, however, solves the problem.

*Later*: in case it matters, I'm running Mongrel 1.1.5 on OSX 10.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your generated routes for problems with "rake routes | grep tag"
2. Check the actual method that is being called, and the verb it is being called with by tail -f log/development.log

This should bring up any obvious problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen with older versions of mongrel, but 1.1.5 is not old. I have also seen some similar problems when the browser double-posts a request to a URL. Is that happening here?

I'd need some more information to be able to help you: What browser are you using? Are you using the firebug plugin on Firefox? What does the server log say about the request, other than the MethodNotAllowed exception?

Answer (score 0):

Somethings to check:

- sometimes you need to restart your server to load new routes.
- TagsController exists?
- index action in TagsController exists?

I'm curious to see the stack trace here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your codes for example related with form_for, to check if has any typo? When you run rake routes, everything is fine? I saw this problem before and it was related with a typo in the form_for parameters.

Did you update your mongrel? gem update mongrel?

Did you check your project log? log*.log?

Regards,

Victor